# When I run my code it works but there are issues when I want to input a jump command. The computer jumps but then keeps dropping down out of my screen

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I've been following Tech with Tim's pygame. However I have reached a point where we are coding jumping. I understand the code but Idon't understand why my computer won't consider the else statement once I have reached jumpCount = -10
Here's the full code for comprehension but it's the part starting from "if not isJump:"

```
x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - (width + vel):
        x += vel
    if not isJump:
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
            y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - (height + vel):
            y += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True

    # So my problem is really here.

    else:
        if isJump >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= ((jumpCount ** 2) * neg) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (x, round(y), width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Your formatting is a bit off. Where does the ‘isJump = True’ occur in your program?

Comment: Sorry for that isJump is part of the while loop above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition is wrong. It has to be `if jumpCount >= -10:` rather than `if isJump >= -10:`:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    if not isJump:
        # [...]

    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= ((jumpCount ** 2) * neg) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10
```